# Как в python взять чтото из json

Tags: python

Я получаю вот такой json

```
[
  {
    "online": "1000",
    "maxonline": "1000",
    "color": "FF0000",
    "x2": "true",
    "key": "1424",
    "name": "BLACK RUSSIA | RED",
    "firstname": "RED",
    "secondname": "(X2 \u0410\u041a\u0426\u0418\u0418)"
  },
  {
    "online": "999",
    "maxonline": "1000",
    "color": "00FF00",
    "x2": "true",
    "key": "1424",
    "name": "BLACK RUSSIA | GREEN",
    "firstname": "GREEN",
    "secondname": "(X2 \u0410\u041a\u0426\u0418\u0418)"
  },
  {
    "online": "1000",
    "maxonline": "1000",
    "color": "2D57EC",
    "x2": "true",
    "key": "1424",
    "name": "BLACK RUSSIA | BLUE",
    "firstname": "BLUE",
    "secondname": "(X2 \u0410\u041a\u0426\u0418\u0418)"
  },
  {
    "online": "1000",
    "maxonline": "1000",
    "color": "FFFF00",
    "x2": "true",
    "key": "1424",
    "name": "BLACK RUSSIA | YELLOW",
    "firstname": "YELLOW",
    "secondname": "(X2 \u0410\u041a\u0426\u0418\u0418)"
  },
  {
    "online": "1000",
    "maxonline": "1000",
    "color": "FFA500",
    "x2": "true",
    "key": "1424",
    "name": "BLACK RUSSIA | ORANGE",
    "firstname": "ORANGE",
    "secondname": "(X2 \u0410\u041a\u0426\u0418\u0418)"
  },
  {
    "online": "1000",
    "maxonline": "1000",
    "color": "800080",
    "x2": "true",
    "key": "1424",
    "name": "BLACK RUSSIA | PURPLE",
    "firstname": "PURPLE",
    "secondname": "(X2 \u0410\u041a\u0426\u0418\u0418)"
  },
  {
    "online": "1000",
    "maxonline": "1000",
    "color": "ccff00",
    "x2": "true",
    "key": "1424",
    "name": "BLACK RUSSIA | LIME",
    "firstname": "LIME",
    "secondname": "(X2 \u0410\u041a\u0426\u0418\u0418)"
  },
  {
    "online": "999",
    "maxonline": "1000",
    "color": "FF69B4",
    "x2": "true",
    "key": "1424",
    "name": "BLACK RUSSIA | PINK",
    "firstname": "PINK",
    "secondname": "(X2 \u0410\u041a\u0426\u0418\u0418)"
  },
  {
    "online": "999",
    "maxonline": "1000",
    "color": "790604",
    "x2": "true",
    "key": "1424",
    "name": "BLACK RUSSIA | CHERRY",
    "firstname": "CHERRY",
    "secondname": "(X2 \u0410\u041a\u0426\u0418\u0418)"
  },
  {
    "online": "1000",
    "maxonline": "1000",
    "color": "33393D",
    "x2": "true",
    "key": "1424",
    "name": "BLACK RUSSIA | BLACK",
    "firstname": "BLACK",
    "secondname": "(X2 \u0410\u041a\u0426\u0418\u0418)"
  },
  {
    "online": "999",
    "maxonline": "1000",
    "color": "4B0082",
    "x2": "true",
    "key": "1424",
    "name": "BLACK RUSSIA | INDIGO",
    "firstname": "INDIGO",
    "secondname": "(X2 \u0410\u041a\u0426\u0418\u0418)"
  },
  {
    "online": "999",
    "maxonline": "1000",
    "color": "FFFFFF",
    "x2": "true",
    "key": "1424",
    "name": "BLACK RUSSIA | WHITE",
    "firstname": "WHITE",
    "secondname": "(X2 \u0410\u041a\u0426\u0418\u0418)"
  },
  {
    "online": "1000",
    "maxonline": "1000",
    "color": "C406C4",
    "x2": "true",
    "key": "1424",
    "name": "BLACK RUSSIA | MAGENTA",
    "firstname": "MAGENTA",
    "secondname": "(X2 \u0410\u041a\u0426\u0418\u0418)"
  },
  {
    "online": "1000",
    "maxonline": "1000",
    "color": "D9133B",
    "x2": "true",
    "key": "1424",
    "name": "BLACK RUSSIA | CRIMSON",
    "firstname": "CRIMSON",
    "secondname": "(X2 \u0410\u041a\u0426\u0418\u0418)"
  },
  {
    "online": "1000",
    "maxonline": "1000",
    "color": "F1B61F",
    "x2": "true",
    "key": "1424",
    "name": "BLACK RUSSIA | GOLD",
    "firstname": "GOLD",
    "secondname": "(X2 \u0410\u041a\u0426\u0418\u0418)"
  },
  {
    "online": "999",
    "maxonline": "1000",
    "color": "3097FF",
    "x2": "true",
    "key": "1424",
    "name": "BLACK RUSSIA | AZURE",
    "firstname": "AZURE",
    "secondname": "(X2 \u0410\u041a\u0426\u0418\u0418)"
  },
  {
    "online": "999",
    "maxonline": "1000",
    "color": "868480",
    "x2": "true",
    "key": "1424",
    "name": "BLACK RUSSIA | PLATINUM",
    "firstname": "PLATINUM",
    "secondname": "(X2 \u0410\u041a\u0426\u0418\u0418)"
  },
  {
    "online": "997",
    "maxonline": "1000",
    "color": "0DEDED",
    "x2": "true",
    "key": "1424",
    "name": "BLACK RUSSIA | AQUA",
    "firstname": "AQUA",
    "secondname": "(X2 \u0410\u041a\u0426\u0418\u0418)"
  },
  {
    "online": "999",
    "maxonline": "1000",
    "color": "C7C2C1",
    "x2": "true",
    "key": "1424",
    "name": "BLACK RUSSIA | GRAY",
    "firstname": "GRAY",
    "secondname": "(X2 \u0410\u041a\u0426\u0418\u0418)"
  },
  {
    "online": "997",
    "maxonline": "1000",
    "color": "B6F1FE",
    "x2": "true",
    "key": "1424",
    "name": "BLACK RUSSIA |  ICE",
    "firstname": "ICE",
    "secondname": "(X2 \u0410\u041a\u0426\u0418\u0418)"
  },
  {
    "online": "999",
    "maxonline": "1000",
    "color": "FE2726",
    "x2": "true",
    "key": "1424",
    "name": "BLACK RUSSIA | CHILLI",
    "firstname": "CHILLI",
    "secondname": "(X2 \u0410\u041a\u0426\u0418\u0418)"
  }
]
```

Допустим я хочу взять из первого сервера онлайн как мне это сделать
P.s я новичок в python
представим что этот json это src

```
url = "https://api.blackrussia.online/servers.json"
headers = {
    "Host": "api.blackrussia.online",
    "Connection": "Keep-Alive",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip",
    "User-Agent": "okhttp/3.12.0"
}
req = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
src = req.text
print(src)
```

Comment: `src = req.json()` вместо `src = req.text`, а дальше как с `dict`

Comment: Ну вернее это вроде список, внутри которого уже словари.

Comment: а спасибо понял